# POSIX permissions for Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I have mounted Azure file share on my Ubuntu VM. Mount point is /mnt/azure_fileshare.

The mount is owned by user "root". I tried changing this to a specific user. But this is not possible. Has any one tried controlling access to a Azure File share from within the server using POSIX permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uid` or `gid` option to set the ownership information, refer to [mount.cifs(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

> uid=arg sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the
>   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric
>   uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper
>   must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in
>   non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND
>   PERMISSIONS below for more information.

For example, the 0700 permission gives read, write, and execute permissions to the file owner, but a group or others could not access it. You can add a specific user to this owner like this.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //$STORAGEACCT.file.core.windows.net/myshare /mnt/MyAzureFileShare -o vers=3.0,username=$STORAGEACCT,password=$STORAGEKEY,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,serverino,uid=someuser
```

[image]